# Several condition for FOR loop with logical AND(&&) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prompt

need your help. I need to check whether it was entered number between 1-7 or not and check whether is empty line or not. What's wrong in my code below:

```
let number = parseInt(prompt('Choose number from 1 to 7'));
    for ( ; (!number) && (number > 7); ) {
        number = parseInt(prompt('Choose from 1 to 7'));
    }
mood(number);
```

variable **number** goes for some function

Comment: How could both conditions be true?

Comment: You are probably looking for `||` instead of `&&`

Comment: Instead of a `for` loop, use a `while` loop. You don't have any bounds on the for loop, so it's essentially a `while` loop.

Comment: On another sidenote, you are not validating for `number < 1` in the current statement. You might want to add that as well c;

Comment: though allowed, number is a bad name since Number() is a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic for which you want to check this requires you to use OR instead of AND operator.
When you are using AND, it is never evaluating 'truthy'.

Try `( ; (!number) || (number > 7); )`instead of `( ; (!number) && (number > 7); )`

Comment: So what about -1?

Answer (score 1):

You need an OR not an AND logical statement.

I would also use a do/while loop for clarity instead of for:

```
let number
do {
  number = parseInt(prompt('Choose number from 1 to 7'));
} while (!number || number < 1 || number > 7);
```

Comment: type in `p` and you will see a bug

Answer (score 0):

You should change your (&&) to (||)

Comment: Thank you! :) I'm new in JS